# Travis CI "rake db:migrate" or "rake db:test:prepare" causes rake aborted! PG::Error: ERROR: relation "settings" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, testing, rake, travis-ci

The relevant travis-ci build is at:
http://travis-ci.org/#!/NZOI/nztrain/builds/2046207

At that point neither db:migrate or db:test:prepare commands work. I have checked that the db/schema.rb file is there, so it should just be able to load the schema into the database.

Github code also available from https://github.com/NZOI/nztrain/tree/a710ef72089ae589a53a7ca0187f73e7f9bf4cc0

Comment: just out of curiosity, how can it build without a ```database.yml```?

Comment: ah, i see, it's copied in ```install.sh```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error caused by:

- rake db:??? runs initializers
- initializer accessed a table, pulling settings stored in the database table called "settings"
- travis-ci starts without any tables in db

Because initializers run before db:?? has a change to create the tables, error occurs